# Are empty macros allowed by the C++ language standard?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to N3092 (final committee draft of C++11), in *16.3: Macro replacement*, object-like macro is defined as:

```
# define identifier replacement-list new-line
```

and function-like macro is defined as:

```
# define identifier lparen identifier-list_opt ) replacement-list new-line
# define identifier lparen ... ) replacement-list new-line
# define identifier lparen identifier-list , ... ) replacement-list new-line
```

All have *replacement-list* (so-called macro value) and this is defined as:

```
replacement-list:
     pp-tokensopt
```

and *pp-tokens* is defined as:

```
pp-tokens:
    preprocessing-token
    pp-tokens preprocessing-token
```

and *preprocessing-token* is, for example, *identifier*.

As far as I read these, a macro with an empty value is well-defined.
**However**, *16.3-3* says:

> There shall be white-space between the identifier and the replacement list in the definition of an object-like macro.

and note that *replacement-list* itself is **not** optional (though it can have an empty value).

So I believe:

```
//well-formed (function-like macro with value)
#define f(x) (x)<NEWLINE>

//well-formed (function-like macro without value)
#define f(x)<NEWLINE>

//well-formed (function-like macro without value)
#define f(x) <NEWLINE>

//well-formed (object-like macro with value)
#define f hello<NEWLINE>

//**ill-formed** (object-like macro without value)
#define f<NEWLINE>

//well-formed (object-like macro without value)
#define f <NEWLINE>
```

and thus, for example, a so-called "include guard" should be of the form:

```
#ifndef is_xyz_included<NEWLINE>
    #define is_xyz_included <NEWLINE> // NOTE THE SPACE BEFORE <NEWLINE>
#endif<NEWLINE>
```

Is my interpretation wrong?

Comment: It's a wording defect. Move on, nothing to see here.

Comment: @n.m.: Wording defects matter. If the intent is clear (as it is in this case, obviously `#define FOO` *should* be valid), then it doesn't directly matter either to implementers or to users. But it's worth pointing out and fixing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe your interpretation is correct. A valid include guard must therefore be of the form you describe, with a white-space that is not a newline. Not a newline because of

> **[cpp]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/cpp#4) The only white-space characters that shall appear between
>   preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive (from just after
>   the introducing # preprocessing token through just before the
>   terminating new-line character) are space and horizontal-tab
>   (including spaces that have replaced comments or possibly other
>   white-space characters in translation phase 3).

which precludes a new-line from being the white-space talked about in the paragraph you mentioned.

But given how common this idiom is with include guards, so much so that [the standard itself contains such an example](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/cpp#6), this is probably a wording defect that is based on the assumption that a replacement list must not be empty for the macro to be of any use.

It's worth mentioning that it's a wording defect shared with the C standard, as far as my survey of the wording found.

Comment: Whitespaces serve to separate tokens. Otherwise they are always optional. Is that not correct?

Comment: @RSahu - Usually. But here is one case in the OP where a white space is required, even if the tokens *can* be separated. For instance `#define f*` is still not valid under that paragraph, even though normally `f*` is two tokens even without the whitespace.

Comment: Thank you. It's seemed a reasonable answer. An additional note: the statement you cite is also found in N3092 16-4 (which I'm reading).

Comment: White-space is limited to spaces and horizontal-tab **between** preprocessing tokens. Therefore white-space not between tokens (because no token followos) may also be new-line.

Comment: @CAF - *"from just after the introducing # preprocessing token through just before the terminating new-line character"* - there is nothing unclear about that. `#` and the identifier are also preprocessing tokens. And as the OP surmised, an empty replacement list is still a replacement list, and needs a white-space.